# Scan code list of characters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ascii, port

I am developing an iPhone application, in which i need to write characters scan code on ports, for this i need to convert characters in ASCII code then convert ASCII to scan code. Can someone help to or send me link of scan code.

Comment: What do you mean by "scan code"? Do you mean a [barcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcode)?

Comment: Excuse me if I didn't read it, but you never told that you're working on VNC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find a [list](http://webster.cs.ucr.edu/AoA/DOS/pdf/apndxc.pdf) of scan code.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPC-A and UPC-E
EAN-8 and EAN-13
Code 39 
Code 93
Code 128
ITF 
Codabar
RSS-14 (all variants)
QR Code 
Data Matrix
Aztec ('beta' quality)
PDF 417 ('alpha' quality)
```

This are scanner available You can use zxing framework which help you out scanning things

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

Comment: thanks and sorry i need scan code for IBM system. i am working on VNC. So i want to write charecters on sockets.